# Backend bucket versioning

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

We have bucket with some files behind the CDN, along with signed URLs. We are using query string with version to update content [according to the best practices](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/best-practices#use_versioned_urls_to_update_content), e.g. file.ext?v=100.

Everthing worked well until the recent time. The documentation now states that backend buckets do not process query strings. However previously we didn’t meet such restriction, so it seems to be a recent change.

Are there any workarounds to achieve near real-time updates? We cannot get rid of CDN because of latency, and cannot change file names as it would require to many code changes. Invalidation is not an option too.

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to? Could it be: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls ?

Answer (score 1):

I got confirmation from Google that this is how the Cloud CDN nowadays works. Backend buckets don't use query strings in the cache key anymore and the only real workaround provided by Google is to use versioning in the object name. It's too bad that this backwards incompatible change was introduced. See also [Google Cloud CDN started ignoring query strings for storage buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280010/google-cloud-cdn-started-ignoring-query-strings-for-storage-buckets)